# How to set RAILS_ENV in Aptana Rad Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I'm using Aptana RadRails, and it seems that whenever I do any rake tasks it is using the development environment.  How do I tell it to use the production environment?

(e.g. db:create sets up my development database.  I know I could do a db:create:all, but I'm wondering how to set the environment.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add RAILS_ENV=production in the parameters text field at the Rake Rasks tab =)